# Join mysql query. Limit 1 on second table only with desc order

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

```
SELECT *
FROM student as std LEFT JOIN
     (SELECT * FROM billing WHERE `paid` < '4' ) AS bill
    ON bill.reg_id = std.reg_id
GROUP BY bill.reg_id
ORDER BY bill.id
```

Here student table is main table and its primary key is foreign key in billing table. 
There are multiple records in billing table with student reg_id .

I want latest billing record with limit 1
and no limit on student table.

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: What you have include in the question has nothing to do with php or mysqli.

Comment: Trying to set limit on billing table.

Comment: SELECT * FROM student as std LEFT JOIN (SELECT * FROM billing WHERE `paid` < '4' LIMIT 1 ORDER BY id DESC ) AS bill ON bill.reg_id = std.reg_id

Comment: SELECT reg_id, id ,name,paid,amount_tobe_pay,paid_ammount,date,note
FROM (
    SELECT reg_id, MAX(id), id ,name,paid,amount_tobe_pay,paid_ammount,date,note
    FROM billing
    GROUP BY reg_id DESC) as ids
ORDER BY reg_id;                                                                                               
            I've tried this but not able to join with student table. This query gives me output but mysql shows error.

Comment: select
* from student as std left join (select MAX(id)  from billing WHERE billing.paid < '4') bill on bill.reg_id = std.reg_id . Also tried this but billing record gives null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try This Query, I think it should work

```
SELECT *
FROM student as std LEFT JOIN
 (SELECT * FROM billing WHERE `paid` < '4' group by reg_id order by id desc) 
 AS bill
ON bill.reg_id = std.reg_id
```

Comment: You can't use `SELECT * ... GROUP reg_id` and trust the results are correct within MySQL.. https://www.psce.com/en/blog/2012/05/15/mysql-mistakes-do-you-use-group-by-correctly/ .. Only when column reg_id has a PRIMARY or UNIQUE key the `SELECT *` can be used because the other columns are functional dependent on the reg_id column

Comment: Thanks man it works. I've already set primary key and foreign key to bill table.

Comment: Still not getting desired result. want single last record of billing table.

Comment: You need Final Output to single Record.? Can please post your desired output sample so that we can help you.

I believe when you use group by regid it will pick only one record for each reg_id

Comment: SELECT reg_id, id ,name,paid,amount_tobe_pay,paid_ammount,date,note
FROM (
    SELECT reg_id, MAX(id), id ,name,paid,amount_tobe_pay,paid_ammount,date,note
    FROM billing
    GROUP BY reg_id DESC) as ids
ORDER BY reg_id;                                                                                               
            I've tried this but not able to join with student table. This query gives me output but mysql shows error.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming there's a column called billing_date, you'll have to update query with the correct timestamp.  This is giving each billing record a rank based on its recency then pulling back only the most recent.  It's assuming mysql 8.0, you can mimic this in earlier version.

```
select
* 
from student std
left join (select
*, row_number() over (partition by reg_id order by billing_date desc) rn
from billing) bill on bill.reg_id = std.reg_id and rn=1
```

Comment: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '(partition by reg_id order by billing_date desc) rn from billing) bill on bill.r' at line 1

Comment: I want all record of student but only one record of bill table of each student.

Comment: I was able to get this working with dummy data on mysql 8.0 and it did what you're looking for.  You may have to add your business logic around the 'paid' <4, but it will only return 1 bill row per student.  Your error may be because you're using an older version of mysql, please advise your mysql version.

Comment: I'm using XAMPP for Windows 5.6.24. and its Server version: 10.1.16-MariaDB - mariadb.org binary distribution.

Comment: row_number was added in Maria 10.2, so may not be a help there. .  Look at the answers here for work around ideas: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1895110/row-number-in-mysql

Comment: SELECT reg_id, id ,name,paid,amount_tobe_pay,paid_ammount,date,note
FROM (
    SELECT reg_id, MAX(id), id ,name,paid,amount_tobe_pay,paid_ammount,date,note
    FROM billing
    GROUP BY reg_id DESC) as ids
ORDER BY reg_id;                                                                                               
            I've tried this but not able to join with student table. This query gives me output but mysql shows error.